# MATLAB's fminsearch terminates with no reason after SAP2000 API analysis is completed

Tags: matlab, api, optimization, fminsearch

I am trying to optimize my numerical model of structure made by SAP2000 v18.1. for this purpose, I obtained API functions in MATLAB and tried to do the optimization by the fminsearch function. MATLAB opens the model, makes the modifications and runs the analysis. Then extracts the data I asked for and does the optimization based on them. But MATLAB SOMETIMES terminates at this point. "MATLAB stopped working" and as I press the "Debug" button the program is closed. I checked the memory usage and it is not the problem. I have tried many times to run the process, sometimes after 2-3 repetitions, the program stops, but now even for the first run it terminates. I guess the problem is within the function which runs the SAP2000 and extracts the data, because that's when the program stops working.
here you can find part of the code I wrote:

```
function [ff] = OptimizeSAPMahsa(Varr)

%% Open SAP model file and unlock
%% update some parameters based on Varr
%% Run model (the analysis model)
ret = SapModel.Analyze.RunAnalysis();

%% Extract results

    NumberResults = 0;
    Obj = cellstr(' ');
    Elm = cellstr(' ');
    ACase = cellstr(' ');
    StepType = cellstr(' ');
    StepNum = reshape(0:1,2,1);
    U1 = reshape(0:1,2,1);
    U2 = reshape(0:1,2,1);
    U3 = reshape(0:1,2,1);
    R1 = reshape(0:1,2,1);
    R2 = reshape(0:1,2,1);
    R3 = reshape(0:1,2,1);
    ObjectElm = 0;

ret = SapModel.Results.Setup.DeselectAllCasesAndCombosForOutput;
ret = SapModel.Results.Setup.SetCaseSelectedForOutput('Time History-16.04');
ret = SapModel.Results.Setup.SetOptionDirectHist(2); %step-by-step output

[ret, NumberResults, Obj, Elm, ACase, StepType, StepNum, U1, U2, U3, R1, R2, R3] = SapModel.Results.JointAcc('66', ObjectElm, NumberResults, Obj, Elm, ACase, StepType, StepNum, U1, U2, U3, R1, R2, R3);
acc66x_1604=U1;
acc66y_1604=U2;

    NumberResults = 0;
    Obj = cellstr(' ');
    Elm = cellstr(' ');
    ACase = cellstr(' ');
    StepType = cellstr(' ');
    StepNum = reshape(0:1,2,1);
    U1 = reshape(0:1,2,1);
    U2 = reshape(0:1,2,1);
    U3 = reshape(0:1,2,1);
    R1 = reshape(0:1,2,1);
    R2 = reshape(0:1,2,1);
    R3 = reshape(0:1,2,1);
    ObjectElm = 0;

 ret = SapModel.Results.Setup.DeselectAllCasesAndCombosForOutput;

 ret = SapModel.Results.Setup.SetCaseSelectedForOutput('Time History-16.04');

ret = SapModel.Results.Setup.SetOptionDirectHist(2); %step-by-step output

[ret, NumberResults, Obj, Elm, ACase, StepType, StepNum, U1, U2, U3, R1, R2, R3] = SapModel.Results.JointAcc('73', ObjectElm, NumberResults, Obj, Elm, ACase, StepType, StepNum, U1, U2, U3, R1, R2, R3);

acc73x_1604=U1;
acc73y_1604=U2;

%% Close Sap2000
ret = SapObject.ApplicationExit(false());
SapModel = 0;
SapObject = 0;

[N66x1604] = SpecLinear(0.005,0.05,acc66x_1604,1);

[N73x1604] = SpecLinear(0.005,0.05,acc73x_1604,1);

[E66x1604] = SpecLinear(0.005,0.05,Joint66_x_1604,9.81);

[E73x1604] = SpecLinear(0.005,0.05,Joint73_x_1604,9.81);

ff=norm((N66x1604 - E66x1604).^2)+norm((N73x1604 - E73x1604).^2);

rezult(count)= ff;

const(:,count)= Varr';

count=count+1;
```

and then the ff value is reported to fminsearch. But the problem would be in the line where I ask for data extraction from model, because MATLAB terminates before closing the SAP2000 file. Does anybody know why ? :(
Thanks

Answer (score 1):

I always use `SapObject.SapModel` in every Ret statement… Try that, it could be something helpful…